# Controlling JS load order in Meteor with nested templates breaks with template.rendered?

Tags: meteor

I've got this template named `index`made up of a bunch of partial templates.

```
<template name="index">
  {{> jumbotron }}
  {{> crew }}
  {{> projects3 }}
  {{> projects2 }}
  {{> faq }}
  {{> contact }}
</template>
```

Say that I've got JS code `page-transitions.js` that requires the DOM of `jumbotron` to be fully loaded in order to run.

It's not enough to simple do:

```
Template.index.rendered = function(){
  // load page-transitions.js
};
```

I HAVE to do

```
Template.jumbotron.rendered = function(){
  // load page-transitions.js here instead
};
```

This can get messy really quick because you need to be VERY specific about which partial templates need which JS code. And different templates could require the same JS code so you can run into a situation where you're loading the same JS code multiple times.

Is there a way to wait until the `index` template has completely rendered EVERYTHING, including all nested child templates, and then run the JS code?

`Meteor.startup()` doesn't work in this case either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a couple of things:

First, just use the classic `jQuery.ready` way. because, why not?

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // stuff.
    });
 });
```

Or you could try `Tracker.afterFlush`:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

   // I know each Template.template.rendered has its own afterFlush, but those
   //   computations are defined way before Meteor.startup so then, theoretically,
   //   the below code should be executed last even if it triggers recomputations here.

   Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
      // stuff.
   });

});
```

Comment: can you do a small project reproduction and put it up on github?

Comment: Bah, what the heck. It's working now. I did a Meteor Uodate and it started working, but I don't believe the update actually updated Meteor...

Comment: Weird.. anyway, look for exceptions thrown by Meteor too.